# Scanning memory accessed by a DLL

Tags: dll, memory

I would like to scan (or alternatively dump) memory that a DLL accesses while it's running. Scanning the application's (EXE) memory is not feasible (too large), and the DLL needs the application to run.

Are there any tools like this?

Comment: how big is the executable?

Comment: @AcidShout The EXE itself is about 14MB, but it uses somewhere around 400-500MB of memory. DLL is 2MB and _should_ use significantly less memory.

Comment: I'm not sure of how much computing power you have, but 500MB is not _that_ much. You should try scanning. If you're on Windows, however, you can set a `PAGE_GUARD` memory protection, and you'll get a notification (as exception) each time the memory is accesed (execute, read, or write).

Comment: @AcidShout I have tried with CheatEngine, and it simply freezes after a few scans. If I could only get the memory the DLL uses, I should be able to find what I need pretty quickly, as well.

Comment: Cheat Engine does way too much stuff and it can freeze really fast. Code a simple DLL which you'll inject into the process, save the memory, and scan it whenever you want (on intervals, on input, w/e suits you the best). I repeat, Cheat Engine is doing too much unnecessary stuff that's slowing it down.

Comment: @AcidShout Thanks, I just found out that  I can actually do that in Python too! Sounds like a feasible project.